# Sorting a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I'm trying to sort through a list of tuples. Each tuple contains a string in the 0th position and a list in the 1st position. For example: `("Billy", ['a','b','c'])`. I wish to sort this list of tuples by the length of their respective lists in the 1st position.

For example,

```
[("Alice", ["x","y"]), ("Billy",['a','b','c']), ("Charles", []), ("Dan", [23])]
```

will be sorted to

```
[("Billy",['a','b','c']), ("Alice", ["x","y"]), ("Dan", [23]), ("Charles", [])]
```

How do I go about this in Python?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `key` parameter in `sort` (in-place) or `sorted` (returns a list) to sort by the length of the list.

```
l = [("Alice", ["x","y"]), ("Billy",['a','b','c']), ("Charles", []), ("Dan", [23])]

>>> sorted(l, key = lambda i: len(i[1]))
[('Charles', []), ('Dan', [23]), ('Alice', ['x', 'y']), ('Billy', ['a', 'b', 'c'])]
```

And if you want longest to shortest, also pass `reverse = True`

```
>>> sorted(l, key = lambda i: len(i[1]), reverse=True)
[('Billy', ['a', 'b', 'c']), ('Alice', ['x', 'y']), ('Dan', [23]), ('Charles', [])]
```